# Find and assign custom object

Tags: typescript

I want to find an object within a list and assign a few of the values to a different object. This is my current attempt, but I feel like this is ugly.

```
this.myResult = {value1: null, value2: null};
this.myArray = [
  { a: 'test1', b: 1, c: {subObject1}},
  { a: 'test2', b: 2, c: {subObject2}}
];

let result = this.myArray.find(myObject => myObject.b === 2);

this.myResult = {
   value1: result.a,
   value2: result.b
}
```

Is there a way for the result of the `Array.find()` function to be returned in another lambda function and assign `myResult` without using a local variable? I am looking for something similar to what is below, and am open to using libraries such as lodash.

```
this.myResult = {value1: null, value2: null};
this.myArray = [
  { a: 'test1', b: 1, c: {subObject1}},
  { a: 'test2', b: 2, c: {subObject2}}

this.myArray
  .find(myObject => myObject.b === 2)
  .then(result => {
    this.myResult = {
      value1: result.a,
      value2: result.b
    }
  });
```

EDIT:

After some talking in the comments, I am looking for something similar to a `.map` after the `.find`

```
this.myResult = {value1: null, value2: null};
this.myArray = [
  { a: 'test1', b: 1, c: {subObject1}},
  { a: 'test2', b: 2, c: {subObject2}}

this.myArray
  .find(myObject => myObject.b === 2)
  .map(result => {
    this.myResult = {
      value1: result.a,
      value2: result.b
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wouldn't that work for you? Assuming there will be only 1 or 0 matching elements in your array.

It will filter the array and return a *list* of matching elements (which in your case will be either 1 or 0 elements). Then, we will reduce the array to a single value and if `filter()` returns an empty array, `reduce()` will return a default value.

```js
this.myArray = [
  { a: 'test1', b: 1, c: {subObject1},
  { a: 'test2', b: 2, c: {subObject2}
];

this.myResult = this.myArray
    .filter(myObject => myObject.b === 2)
    .reduce((res, curr) => {
        return {
            value1: curr.a,
            value2: curr.b
        }
    }, {value1: null, value2: null});
```

Answer (score 1):

I'll focus on what you tried to do in your second code sample where you wrote about the solution you'd like (with the `.then()`).

This function chaining idea is to do consecutive operations on a value. This is easy if you're working with iterable items like arrays.

Example:

```js
[1, 2, 3].map(fn1).toSorted(fn2).with(fn3)
```

In this case every function in the chain takes a callback which will be called for each element in the array.
The problem comes now, what if you just want to take the result of the previous operation and just call a function with it in the same chain?

Similar to your case:

```js
// Note: `.doOperation()` is similar to your `.then()`. 
// I just avoid it because it can be confused with promises.
arr.find(fn1).doOperation((val) => ...)
```

This isn't something you can do in javascript unfortunately. In other languages this idea is called piping and they even have a separate operator for it. Basically you want to "pipe" the result of the previous expression to another one.

Note: There is proposal at stage 2 for a piping operator: https://github.com/tc39/proposal-pipeline-operator

If this proposal gets merged in the future you'll be able to do something like this:

```js
let result = arr.find(fn1) |> (foundValue) => {
  return {
    a: foundValue.a,
    b: foundValue.b
  }
}
```

---

You can definitely can find some way of using something like `.reduce()` or `.forEach()` to achieve this without using a temp variable, but it won't be exactly what you're looking for.
If you just want to get rid of the temp variable you can also write an [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE) like this:

```js
let arr = [
  { a: 'test1', b: 1, c: {subObject1}},
  { a: 'test2', b: 2, c: {subObject2}},
  { a: 'test3', b: 3, c: {subObject3}},
];

let res = (({ a, b }) => ({ a, b }))(arr.find(obj => obj.b === 2))
```